# WPF - Binding to ListView cannot work

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

Code Behind, I try to bind the ListView with the ObserableCollection PackageInfos. However, when I run it, it shows no information. Can someone help to slove it?

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {           
            InitializeComponent();

            PackageInfos = new ObservableCollection<PackageInfo>();

            polulatePackageInfos();

            DataContext = this;
        }        

        public ObservableCollection<PackageInfo> PackageInfos { get; private set; }

        private void polulatePackageInfos()
        {
            PackageInfos.Add(new PackageInfo() { Name = "Apple", priceRate = "10", imageUrl = "images/GreatWallofChina.jpg" });
            PackageInfos.Add(new PackageInfo() { Name = "Beijing", priceRate = "6", imageUrl = "images/GreatWallofChina.jpg" });
            PackageInfos.Add(new PackageInfo() { Name = "China", priceRate = "4", imageUrl = "images/GreatWallofChina.jpg" });
        }
    }
```

xaml section

```
<Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" 
        Height="585" 
        Width="320"                
        x:Class="VendingMachine.MainWindow
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:VendingMachine">

    <Grid Style="{StaticResource GridStyler}">

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="3*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="3*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="3*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <ScrollViewer ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"                       
                      ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" 
                      PanningMode="Both"
                      Grid.Row="1">

            <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding PackageInfos, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" >
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:PackageInfo}">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding priceRate}" />                           
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>

        </ScrollViewer>       

    </Grid>

</Window>
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont have all your code. specifically the class for PackageInfo
Im betting this class is incorrect. it should look like

```
public class PackageInfo
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string priceRate { get; set; }
    public string imageUrl { get; set; }
}
```

i used your code with this class and it displayed fine for me.
oh i also had to remove the grid styler from your XAML as well because i dont have that code.

Comment: I know the reason already. I have no getter for PackageInfo's property. Thank you!